# Javascript For-Loop issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, for-loop

I'm trying to click every item with a 200 millisecond interval, I wrote the following script however there seems to be an issue with the For Loop. Some one please tell me what you think is wrong with it.

```
function clickLink(elm) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function sel() {
    elms = document.getElementsByClassName('uItem');
    var inputs= elms;
    var howbig= elms.length;
    console.log(howbig);

    for (var i=250;i<elms.length;i++)
    {
        setTimeout(clickLink(inputs[i]),200)
    };
```

There's 1400 uItem 's on the page.

Comment: What happens when you run it? What led you to the conclusion that the for-loop is the problem?

Comment: @JaniHartikainen With or without the for loop in the equation all that happens is i get a console message that sais 1400 (the amount of UItem's on the page yet none are clicked.

Comment: You are passing the function's return value to the setTimeout instead of a function reference.

Comment: you want to click all items at the same time, or clicking each item one by one, spaced 200 ms?

Comment: @BAK I would like a 200ms pause between each click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your doing this won't get you one click per 200ms, you will register all your clicks almost at the same time(the time a loop last to iterate 1000 items,almost instantly) so you basically would get your 1000+ aprox. click events fired almost simultaneously, I think that could cause issues, so to make sure they are executed once in a 200ms approx. do this:

```
window.i=250;
for (var i=250;i<elms.length;i++)
{
setTimeout(function() {
   clickLink(inputs[window.i]);
   window.i++;
},200 * (i-249)); //Here we make sure events are spaciated 200ms each approx.
};
```

**UPDATE:** <strike>Updated the anonymouse function to pass `i` to avoid closure issue noted in comments.</strike>

**UPDATE 2**: Added `window.i` inside anonymous function to workaround `i` scope issue

**UPDATE 3**: Updated my code above to fix the interval at which each click event is fired, we were using `200 * i` but that is only correct if `i` starts at zero, here it starts at 250 so the correct form is `200 * (i-249)`

In spite of some comments, the `i` scope issue it's resolved using `window.i` , see test here https://tinker.io/98fd4/1

Comment: Added an argument to the function doesn't work either, because when `setTimeout` calls its argument function, it does so with no arguments. Thus `i` will always be `null`.

Comment: You can only add the argument if you pass `i` after the duration. Also, it doesn't work in some browsers to pass arguments to the callback.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the scopping issue, I've made an update to mitigate the issue using a global var inside the anonymous function.

Comment: Using `window.i` is the opposite direction you want to go. You need the scope to be *more* local, not less.

Comment: Nothing happens in your example, but no, I'm not wrong. All the callbacks passed to `setTimeout` are using the same `window.i` variable. Since none of them actually run until the loop is finished, by the time they run, `window.i` will be the value of `elms.length` instead of the desired value from the loop,.

Comment: `window.i` doesn't fail because it fails to function. It fails because using a global for this purpose leads to unreliable code, since the tramples on the most basic principles of encapsulation.

Comment: @user1689607 Just open the console to see the output of my example, you will see `window.i` receives correct values inside the anonymous function..

Comment: @Nelson: Oh I see. I thought you were using `window.i` for the counter too. My bad. Not a pretty solution maintaining two counters, but it works I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick! The window.i var was giving me isues prior but when defined above the for loop it no longer gave me issues and it worked out. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Cleanest solution is just to have your `clickLink` function return a function.

```
function clickLink(elm) {
    return function() {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
    };
}
```

Then stagger the timers if you want an interval:

```
var start = 250
for (var i=start;i<elms.length;i++) {
    setTimeout(clickLink(elms[i]), 200 * (i - start))
}
```

Or ditch the loop, and use `setInterval`:

```
var i = 250,
    len = inputs.length;
var itvl = setInterval(function() {
    clickLink(elms[i++]);
    if (i >= len)
        clearInterval(itvl);
}, 200);
```

And to back to your original `clickLink` function

Comment: This is the explicit way of returning a bound function, as I mentioned in my answer. My experience with relatively complex landing function for asynchronous operations (in my case it was AJAX, but the flow of control is identical), is that I found the code cleaner when I relied on `bind` to do the same. Using that call makes it explicit when the arguments are evaluated and kept my head straight more easily.

Comment: You need to better adjust your `200 * i` interval, see the **UPDATE 3** of my answer.

Comment: @Nelson: Yeah, good point. I forgot about the starting point.

Comment: +1 for your solution and the feedback gave to others solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, if you're using a moderately-recent version of JavaScript, is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). This creates a single function object with arguments bound to it that are calculated when `bind` is called, not later. The line you want is thus:

```
setTimeout( clickLink.bind( null, inputs[i] ),  /* delay expression here */ )
```

You can make bound functions explicitly, but it's ugly and you should only do it if you have a strong requirement to support old JavaScript interpreters.

Comment: I like the `.bind` solution, but you're binding the `this` value of the function, so you'd need to either pass a different value as the first argument before `inputs[i]`, or you'd need to change the `clickLink` function to use `this` instead of `elm`.

Comment: In the present example, that doesn't matter, because `this` isn't used in `clickLink`. In general, though, I agree that you have to pay attention to the value of `this` you get.

Comment: I agree, `this` isn't used, and that's the trouble. The `elm` parameter will be `undefined` because nothing is passed, and nothing is bound.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Brain fart. Fixed. I was so used to constructing bound functions explicitly I got the signature of `bind` wrong in my head.

Answer (score 2):

There is a issue of the scope of `ì`, the delay which needs to be incremented accordingly with `i` to have a 200 ms interval and the fact that `setTimeout` expects a function as is argument.

```
    for (var i=250;i<elms.length;i++)
    {
        setTimeout((function() {
            var j = i // keep i as j in this closure
            return function() { // return the right function
                clickLink(inputs[j])
            }
        })(),200 * i) // set the delay depending on i
    };
```

Comment: The value of `i` inside the anonymous function is not the `i` of the loop variable, because the loop is not in scope when the anonymous function executes. Unless `i` is in scope as a global (shudder), its value will be `null`.

Comment: what makes you say i isn't in scope?

Comment: `i` is definitely in a reachable scope of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sel() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('uItem');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    setTimeout(function (el) {
      return function () {
        clickLink(el);
      };
    }(elems[i]), i * 1000);   
  };
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hYWy/

---

*little note*: I don't like these constructs (calculating the delay like in the example). But it is very close to the original code, and my solution of choice would have probably made it too complicated.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that you can make bound functions explicitly. This answer is an example of how that's done, with a function that returns a function.

Answer (score 2):

This code wait 200ms, execute a callback and prepare a new callback executed 200ms later.
The second callback is executed 400ms after the call of `sel` and so on.

```
    var callback = function(i) {
        return function() {
            if (i < elms.length) {
                clickLink(inputs[i]);
                setTimeout(callback(i + 1), 200);
            }
        };
    };
    setTimeout(callback(250), 200);
```

Comment: Most of the other answers multiply `200 * i` so they're not executed at the same time. But take a look at your returned function. You are invoking it immediately, so it never gets passed to the `setTimeout`. You'll need to remove the trailing `()` from the returned function.

Comment: +1 because I do like this solution. But there's one more problem. The increment  of `i` is done after the comparison to `.length`, so on the last call, `i` will be equal to `elms.length`, which means `inputs[i]` will be `undefined`. You should make the `clickLink(inputs[i])` conditional as well.

Answer (score 1):

No scope issues or calculating correct interval.

```
function sel() {
    var elms = document.getElementsByClassName('uItem'),
        i = -1,
        I = elms.length,

        rec = function () {
            if ( i++ < I ) {
                clickLinks(elms[i]);
                setTimeout(rec, 200);
            }
        };

    rec();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/cqfxH/